# Select query as where condition in Exposed

Tags: kotlin-exposed

How to use DSL method to generate a `SELECT` query in `WHERE`?

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM table
    GROUP BY name
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Now `Exposed` have added `InSubQueryOp`.

```
Table.run {
    select { id inSubQuery slice(id.max()).selectAll().groupBy(column) }
}
```

---

After searching I found [this issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/252) on GitHub. `wrapAsExpression` can be use to compose subquery.

1. Copy `EqOp` and transform it to `InOp`

   ```
   class InOp(expr1: Expression<*>, expr2: Expression<*>) : ComparisonOp(expr1, expr2, "IN")
   ```
2. Copy `eq` then transform it to `inExpr` extension function

   ```
   infix fun<T, S1: T?, S2: T?> Expression<in S1>.inExpr(other: Expression<in S2>) : 
   Op<Boolean> = InOp(this, other)
   ```
3. Use them

   ```
   Table.run {
       select { id inExpr wrapAsExpression(slice(id.max()).selectAll().groupBy(column)) }
   }
   ```

Example output:

```
SELECT `user`.id, `user`.name, FROM `user` WHERE `user`.id IN (SELECT MAX(`user`.id) FROM `user` GROUP BY `user`.name)
```